# How to apply a style to both parent and child in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have this situation:

```
<div class="parent">
     <a class="child"></a>
</div>
```

and I wanto to give width: 100% rule to both. Is there a better way in SCSS rather than writing:

```
.parent{
    width: 100%;
    .child{
        width: 100%;
    }
 }
```

I am rather new to SCSS syntax, and so maybe it is a very simple question, but nowhere I can find a simple answer.

Answer (score 34):

You target the current selector with `&`, so you could write:

```
.parent {
  &, .child {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

As a bonus, you also use `&` as follows:

```
.parent {
  &.mother {
    // target elements classed `parent` AND `mother`

    .grandparent & {
      // target elements classed `parent` AND `mother` with a 
      // `grandparent` ancestor.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that means that if I add the comma (,) the & operator will add the property also to the targeted element, and not like if I remove the comma, to the  .parent (plus) .child class. Am I right? Want I mean: if I wrote || .parent { &.child { ... } }  ||  the rule wuold be added to the <div class="parent child"> element....

Comment: It's the space that matters.  `& .child` (note the space) will target `.child` under the current selection. `&.child` will increase the specificity of the current selection to **also** have the `.child` class.  The comma in my answer is because it's targeting *both* `.parent` and `.parent .child`.

Answer (score -10):

Try not setting `width` on the child element at all :)