# How can I generate a style for parent and a number of descendants in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I want to generate this kind of CSS, where a style is applied to an element and several of its descendants, using SCSS

```css
.a, 
.a .b, 
.a .b .c,
.a .b .c .d { /* Styles */ }
```

In this related question [How to apply a style to both parent and child in SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393346/) I learned that I could achieve something similiar using `&`. I've tried this:

```scss
.a {
  &, .b {
    &, .c {
      &, .d {
        color: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which resulted in the following css:

```css
.a, 
.a .d, /* Not wanted */
.a .c, /* Not wanted */
.a .c .d, /* Not wanted */
.a .b, 
.a .b .d, /* Not wanted */
.a .b .c, 
.a .b .c .d {
  color: blue;
}
```

I understand that this happens, because `&` will include the *whole previous selection*, which always includes `.a` (or `.a .b` on the next stage).

However, I'm not sure how to fix this.

**Is it possible to get the result I want using SCSS?**

---

Please note that I'm mainly asking out of curiosity and that I'm not very familiar with some aspects of SCSS. Mabye functions, interpolation or mixins could be used?

### Retrictions

- Selectors could be much longer and much more complex then in the example above. I would like to repeat them only as often as necessary.
- There could be many more styles I want to apply, not just one.

### Discarded solutions

Some obvious, but rather bad solutions I could think of

- hard-coding it exactly as I would do in plain CSS. Well the point of question is how to avoid exactly this ;)
- repeating the style on each level. Even with variables this would be more repetition then hard-coding it. I mean something like this:

  ```css
  .a {
    color: blue;
    .b {
      color: blue;
      .c { ...
  ```
- using `color: inherit`. In this case I would still need to repeat the inherit.

Comment: Don't have a full example but I think this should be possible using [each](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) or [for](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) in SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correctly, but if *b*, *c*, *d*,... are all children of *a* I think you might use [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), doing something like:

```
.a > .b > .c > .d { 
   color :  blue
}
```

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that would only style the last element. It wouldn't target `.a` or `.b`. My first example shows the CSS I'd like to generate, which would also target the parents.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `sass` code below can make the selectors you want. Notice that `color` property is an **Inherited** property and is not good for testing in this case, so I used another property to test my code for this example. Also notice that `.b`, `.c` and so on in the `$selectorMain` variable must have a space before to work correctly:

```
@use "sass:list";
@use "sass:string";
$selectorMain: (".a", " .b", " .c", " .d");
$nextLevel: list.nth($selectorMain, 1);
$finalList: ();
@for $i from 1 through list.length($selectorMain) {
  $currentElement: list.nth($selectorMain, $i);
  @if $i >= 2 {
    $nextLevel: string.insert($nextLevel, $currentElement, -1);
  }
  $finalList: list.append($finalList, $nextLevel);
}
@debug $finalList;
@each $selector in $finalList {
  #{$selector} {
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

This is the `html` code that I used to test my sass result:

```html
<div>
  <div class="a">
    <p>div with "a" class</p>
    <div class="b">
      <p>div with "b" class</p>
      <div class="c">
        <p>div with "c" class</p>
        <div class="d">
          div with "d" class
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="a">
    <p>div with "a" class</p>
      <div class="c">
        <p>div with "c" class</p>
        <div class="d">
          div with "d" class
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```